# Can I #include "arduino.h" in regular C++ program on Bigger Linux for Galileo?

Tags: c++, c, linux, arduino, intel-galileo

.. And Also, can the Galileo run a sketch whilst being a Linux?

So can I flash i.e. Blink Sketch to the arduino-bit of the board and have it do Blink while I sit there and watch Star Wars on Telnet on the Linux bit of the Board?

If so I'm gonna have a sickeningly awesome little printer.

Comment: It came with Windows, and that's pretty much what you do..?

Answer (score 0):

This thread at Intel Communities kind of covers it. I had to be pretty specific with my googling though, so maybe this will help someone. https://communities.intel.com/message/251508

Synopsis: You can upload sketches to the Galileo from 'somewhere', and from the Linux on the board you simply run the sketch as an executable (it will also run on boot) - assuuming the permissions of the sketch file are correct and the sketch is in the right directory.